# Dynamically switch method on inherited type

Tags: c#, object, abstract-class

In C# I know there is a way of switching method calls based on the concrete type of an abstract parameter at run time.

So in the example below the entire Wash(Animal) method is not needed and C# will know which Cat/Dog method to call based on the concrete type of Animal at run time. There's syntax to do this, I've done this before but I can't for the life of me remember what it is.

```
    public void Wash(Animal animal)
    {
        switch (animal)
        {
            case Cat cat:
                Wash(cat);
                break;
            case Dog dog:
                Wash(dog);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Wash(Cat cat)
    {

    }

    public void Wash(Dog dog)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the `dynamic` type? That does binding (including overload resolution) at execution time instead of compile time.

Comment: How did you call these methods and create `Cat` and `Dog` instances? Maybe you are looking at generic method, like `Wash<T>(T animal) where T: Animal {}`?

Comment: maybe he's after double dispatch

Answer (score 0):

Could be done using double dispatch...

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract void TakeBath(AnimalWasher washer);
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public override void TakeBath(AnimalWasher washer)
    {
        washer.Wash(this);
    }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public override void TakeBath(AnimalWasher washer)
    {
        washer.Wash(this);
    }
}

class AnimalWasher
{
    public void Wash(Cat cat)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("washing a cat");
    }

    public void Wash(Dog dog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("washing a dog");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        AnimalWasher washer = new AnimalWasher();
        Animal dog = new Dog();
        Animal cat = new Cat();

        dog.TakeBath(washer);
        cat.TakeBath(washer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr Skeet for scratching my itch. Dynamic binding is exactly what I was trying to remember.

```
    public void PetGroom(Animal animal)
    {
        Wash(animal as dynamic);
    }

    public void Wash(Cat cat)
    {

    }

    public void Wash(Dog dog)
    {

    }
```